# Ios app : localisation and storyboard

Tags: ios, localization

My application is based on storyboard.

I want to localise it for several languages and customise it for iPad.

To simplify maintenance, It makes sense to avoid to have two storyboards for each language (one for iPhone and one for iPad).

So, I want to develop and maintain only two storyboards (one for iPhone and one for iPad) and to localize labels programmatically.

But...I do not succeed to localize (programmatically) labels for buttons in a tool bar (several pages have a tool bar bottom screen AND a navigation bar on top).

Google gives tons of indications on this topic but not working in my case : button labels in the tool bar do not change at all.

I am using ios6.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found no other solution than to programmatically localize GUI elements.

So, I have only two storyboards : one for iPhone and another for iPad.

Before to take this route I explored without success the "Use Base Internationalization" option.